# Error connecting to a global Python Socket server

Tags: python, sockets, server

Decided to study what is a server and how to create it.With the first point coped but with its creation there was a problem.For the test decided to create a chat for 2 users (me and my friend). At me on the PC all works well when my friend threw the file that would test there was an error text which I will post below.

Here is how server.py looks like

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 65432  
print(HOST)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Here is how client.py looks like

```
import socket

HOST = "тут ip которое я получил таким путём socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) себя на пк" 
PORT = 65432 

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello, world")
    data = s.recv(1024)

print(f"Received {data!r}")
```

Error that occurred in client.py on a friend's PC

File "C:\Users\Username\Downloads\client.py", line 7, in s.connect((HOST, PORT)) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

tried to look up the answer to the question on the Internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problem #1: a firewall does not allow an incoming connection to that port.

Possible problem #2: you are trying to connect over Internet. It will not work due to a mechanism called NAT. It is difficult - often impossible - to open a connection to an ISP client, because clients do not have a valid public address. I don't want to repeat the known facts about decades long IPv4 address shortage, NAT, private addresses, etc. Please continue your search on Internet for details if you want.

Comment: > HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())  -- On most cases this will resolve in to 127.0.0.1 and if the client is not explicitly using HOST='127.0.0.1' or its running on different machine - NAT or not, combination will not work..